# What software to use if I want to visually identify the colors of a picture on the color wheel?

Tags: color

Let's say I have an image and I want to know the color composition or scheme of it. I could use the color picker tool to select the colors but what I really want to see is all the colors being identified on a color wheel so that I can easily see the color scheme used, be it complementary, opposite or adjacent so that I can have a clear visual clue.

I've been looking around and haven't been able to find one yet. Anyone knows where to find it?

Comment: I recall a website, I think from Adobe, which you uploaded a picture and it did just that. Will try to find a link and post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Adobe Color](http://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel/).

Also this site has a lot of info:
[LearnToCodeWith.me](https://learntocodewith.me/posts/color-palette-tools/)

Comment: Thank you! It's not exactly what I'm looking for but it gets the job done much more effectively!